# How to map properties at different levels

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I'm trying to map my `OptionDTO` in order to fill also `Quantity` property mapping it from `ProductOptions`. `OptionDTO` properties like `Id` and `Name` need to be mapped from `Options` object.

I've tried with a lot of time but now I'm stuck with `AutomapperConfigurationException`:

```
Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.
```

```cs
public partial class Products
    {
        public Products()
        {
            ProductOptions = new HashSet<ProductOptions>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ExtId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string ImgsUrls { get; set; }
        public int? Discount { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateInsert { get; set; }
        public string UserInsert { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdate { get; set; }
        public string UserUpdate { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public bool Private { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductCategories Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProductOptions> ProductOptions { get; set; }
    }

public partial class ProductOptions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Options Option { get; set; }
        public virtual Products Product { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Options
    {
        public Options()
        {
            ProductOptions = new HashSet<ProductOptions>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductOptions> ProductOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

DTOs

```cs
public class OptionDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ExtId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string[] ImgsUrls { get; set; }
        public int? Discount { get; set; }
        public bool Private { get; set; }
        public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OptionDTO> ProductOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

These are my maps:

```cs
CreateMap<Options, OptionDTO>();
            CreateMap<Products, ProductDTO>()
                .ForMember(m => m.ImgsUrls, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ImgsUrls.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
                .ForMember(m => m.ProductOptions, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ProductOptions.Select(y => y.Option)))
                .ForMember(m => m.ProductOptions.Select(s=>s.Quantity), opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ProductOptions))
                .ForMember(m => m.ProductCategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Category.Name));
```

How can I solve my problem?
There are similar question on stack overflow but they cannot help me because this case is a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

```cs
CreateMap<ProductOptions, OptionDTO>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Quantity))
                .ForMember(m => m.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Option.Id))
                .ForMember(m => m.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Option.Name));
CreateMap<Products, ProductDTO>()
                .ForMember(m => m.ImgsUrls, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ImgsUrls.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
                .ForMember(m => m.ProductCategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Category.Name));
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers